# Forge Viewer: How to use Units?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I retrieved the properties of a room from the Viewer and found that its units are `autodesk.unit.unit:millimeters-1.0.1`. How can I convert this to its common name? Is there a way to use this definition for unit conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the model's unit through the method [getUnitString](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getunitstring).

This unit is defined by your project settings.

Comment: How do I get without javascript library ? let's say I'm working with python or c# langauge ?